# Pass method, created with reflection, as Func parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, methods, func

I've got a method (fyi, I'm using c#), accepting a parameter of type "Func", let's say it's defined as such:

```
MethodAcceptingFuncParam(Func<bool> thefunction);
```

I've defined the function to pass in as such:

```
public bool DoStuff()
{
    return true;
}
```

I can easily call this as such:

```
MethodAcceptingFuncParam(() =>  { return DoStuff(); });
```

This works as it should, so far so good.

Now, instead of passing in the DoStuff() method, I would like to create this method through reflection, and pass this in:

```
Type containingType = Type.GetType("Namespace.ClassContainingDoStuff");
MethodInfo mi = containingType.GetMethod("DoStuff");
```

=> this works, I can get the methodinfo correctly.

But this is where I'm stuck: I would now like to do something like

```
MethodAcceptingFuncParam(() => { return mi.??? });
```

In other words, I'd like to pass in the method I just got through reflection as the value for the Func param of the MethodAcceptingFuncParam method.  Any clues on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53cz7sc6.aspx), if the types are appropriate.

For example:

```
var func = (Func<bool>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<bool>), mi);
MethodAcceptingFuncParam(func);
```

Note that if the function is executed a lot in `MethodAcceptingFuncParam`, this will be *much* faster than calling `mi.Invoke` and casting the result.

Answer (score 1):

Use Invoke:

```
MethodAcceptingFuncParam(() => { return (bool)mi.Invoke(null, null); })
```